# alert statement not blocking in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

IM using the below code to check if a session is valid and run every 15 seconds......When I test this piece of code in IE it works fine but ie;alert stmt pops up and once I click "OK" it redirects to the main page...but when I run in chrome it directly redirects to home page without any pop up..

How can I fix this issue ie;chrome should pop up the alert stmt?

```
setInterval(checksession, 15000)

function checksession() {
    $.ajax({
        aynsc: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'CheckSession',
        success: validateresult,
        data: {
            antiCSRF: '{{acsrf}}',
            session_id: '{{session_id}}'
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Session check failed')
        }
    })
    return false;
}

function validateresult(result) {
    if (result == "N") {
        valid_flag = "N"
        alert("Your session has been timed-out based upon Security Policy. Please click OK to be redirected to the login page to start a new session.");
        window.location.assign('./')
    } else {
        valid_flag = "Y";
        return valid_flag
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using "confirm" instead?

Comment: can't you use confirm, is alert really required.

Comment: My suggestion would be to never use alert. Get a plugin or build yourself custom alert. It will be prettier and better!

Comment: Could you post what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I don't see where do you call the validateresult function if the ajax goes wrong?

Comment: I can't user confirm..Only 'alert' stmt..